# LightDM displays wake immediately after sleep

Tags: debian, i3, lightdm

Update 2: The behavior only happens when both monitors are enabled and when lightdm-gtk-greeter is active. Disconnecting or disabling (with xrandr) results in expected behavior.

Update: Seems to have nothing to do with light-locker actually. Setting dpms with a display-setup script for LightDM exhibits the same behavior (sleeping and then immediately waking) before i3 is initialized and with light-locker completely removed and purged. Disabling dpms and setting the screensaver to noblank with xset results in the screensaver working as expected, but the monitors stay powered on. It is seeming like when the screens blank, some event is triggered as @WayneWerner suggested below but I'm not sure how to identify what that event would be.

I am using i3 on Debian testing/sid and have lightdm and light-locker configured. I am also not using any additional power-manager like tpu or xfce4-power-manager. I recently upgraded GPU and went from using a proprietary nVidia driver to AMDGPU. An unexpected side effect has occurred: now when xset initiates a lock with light-locker, lightdm is brought up, the monitors go to sleep and 2-3 seconds afterword the monitors wake up with no additional input. When the configured lightdm-gtk-greeter screensave-timeout is triggered the process occurs again, monitors sleep then immediately wake up again and this process continues indefinitely. I would like for the monitors to sleep and stay asleep until awoken like they did with my nVidia card. I'm sure I have something configured incorrectly, I'm just not sure where.

The GPU and graphics driver are the only things that have changed in this situation.

Here are the contents of my current lightdm config files.

/etc/lightddm/lightdm.conf

```
[LightDM]

[Seat:*]
greeter-hide-users=false

[XDMCPServer]

[VNCServer]
```

/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf

```
[greeter]
theme-name = Breeze-Dark
active-monitor = DisplayPort-1
screensaver-timeout = 10
```

Comment: Have you checked dmesg & such to see if anything is emitting an HDMI wake or some such? (assuming it's an HDMI and not VGA)

Comment: @WayneWerner I don't see anything like that in dmesg although I'm not super sure what I'd be looking for there. It's starting to look like it might be completely separate from light locker as I've now gotten it to reproduce the behavior before launching the WM just in lightdm. I will update the question as I figure out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a mitigation than a solution, but one I'm happy with. Disabling output on the non-primary monitor on LightDM initialization and enabling dpms results in a successful monitor timeout that remains asleep. Configured as follows:

LightDM Config

```
[LightDM]

[Seat:*]
greeter-hide-users=false
display-setup-script=/etc/lightdm/display-config

[XDMCPServer]

[VNCServer]
```

/etc/lightdm/display-config

```bash
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --off --output DisplayPort-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --rate 75
xset dpms 10 10 10 s 10
```

These settings are overwritten in the user context with the following script ran from .xinitrc

```bash
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 75 --output DisplayPort-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --rate 75 --left-of HDMI-A-0
xset dpms 600 600 600 s 600
```

It's messier than I'd like but fine for now.